# Supremum of Unsigned Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

How do you show that the Supremum of unsigned Lebesgue measurable functions is measurable?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unsigned'?

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$.

Answer (score 1):

Non-negativity is not required here.

See Rudin, "Real & Complex Analysis", Theorem 1.14.

Let $g = \sup_n f_n$, and choose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $g^{-1} (\alpha, \infty] = \cup_n f_n^{-1} (\alpha, \infty] $. Since the $f_n$ are measurable, it follows that $g^{-1} (\alpha, \infty]$ is measurable for all $\alpha$, hence $g$ is measurable.

Comment: Why the downvote after 7 years? If there is something wrong please let me know.